# How to pass method name as a parmeter?

Tags: c#, methods, refactoring

I'm looking for a way to make my code shorter. Since a big part of my code is repeatable, is there any way to pass a sub method name as a parmeter?

Here is a some bigger part to make my problem some more clear:

```
Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        int[] ArrayRandom = new int[200000];
        for (int j = 0; j < ArrayRandom.Length; j++) ArrayRandom[j] = rnd.Next(int.MaxValue);

        Console.WriteLine("\nInsertionSort\nARRAY SIZE:\t TIME [ms]:");
        for (int u = 50000; u <= 200000; u += 10000)
        {
            int[] TestArray = new int[u];
            Array.Copy(ArrayRandom, TestArray, u);
            double ElapsedSeconds;
            long ElapsedTime = 0, MinTime = long.MaxValue, MaxTime = long.MinValue, IterationElapsedTime;
            for (int n = 0; n < (NIter + 1 + 1); ++n)  
            {
                long StartingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                InsertionSort(TestArray);
                long EndingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                IterationElapsedTime = EndingTime - StartingTime;
                ElapsedTime += IterationElapsedTime;
                if (IterationElapsedTime < MinTime) MinTime = IterationElapsedTime;
                if (IterationElapsedTime > MaxTime) MaxTime = IterationElapsedTime;
            }
            ElapsedTime -= (MinTime + MaxTime);
            ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedTime * (1000.0 / (NIter * Stopwatch.Frequency));
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}\t{1}", u, ElapsedSeconds.ToString("F4"));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nSelectionSort\nARRAY SIZE:\t TIME [ms]:");
        for (int u = 50000; u <= 200000; u += 10000)
        {
            int[] TestArray = new int[u];
            Array.Copy(ArrayRandom, TestArray, u);

            double ElapsedSeconds;
            long ElapsedTime = 0, MinTime = long.MaxValue, MaxTime = long.MinValue, IterationElapsedTime;
            for (int n = 0; n < (NIter + 1 + 1); ++n)  
            {
                long StartingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                SelectionSort(TestArray);
                long EndingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                IterationElapsedTime = EndingTime - StartingTime;
                ElapsedTime += IterationElapsedTime;
                if (IterationElapsedTime < MinTime) MinTime = IterationElapsedTime;
                if (IterationElapsedTime > MaxTime) MaxTime = IterationElapsedTime;
            }
            ElapsedTime -= (MinTime + MaxTime);
            ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedTime * (1000.0 / (NIter * Stopwatch.Frequency));
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}\t{1}", u, ElapsedSeconds.ToString("F4"));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nCoctailSort\nARRAY SIZE:\t TIME [ms]:");
        for (int u = 50000; u <= 200000; u += 10000)
        {
            int[] TestArray = new int[u];
            Array.Copy(ArrayRandom, TestArray, u);

            double ElapsedSeconds;
            long ElapsedTime = 0, MinTime = long.MaxValue, MaxTime = long.MinValue, IterationElapsedTime;
            for (int n = 0; n < (NIter + 1 + 1); ++n)  
            {
                long StartingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                CocktailSort(TestArray);
                long EndingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                IterationElapsedTime = EndingTime - StartingTime;
                ElapsedTime += IterationElapsedTime;
                if (IterationElapsedTime < MinTime) MinTime = IterationElapsedTime;
                if (IterationElapsedTime > MaxTime) MaxTime = IterationElapsedTime;
            }
            ElapsedTime -= (MinTime + MaxTime);
            ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedTime * (1000.0 / (NIter * Stopwatch.Frequency));
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}\t{1}", u, ElapsedSeconds.ToString("F4"));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nHeapSort\nARRAY SIZE:\t TIME [ms]:");
        for (int u = 50000; u <= 200000; u += 10000)
        {
            int[] TestArray = new int[u];
            Array.Copy(ArrayRandom, TestArray, u);

            double ElapsedSeconds;
            long ElapsedTime = 0, MinTime = long.MaxValue, MaxTime = long.MinValue, IterationElapsedTime;
            for (int n = 0; n < (NIter + 1 + 1); ++n)  
            {
                long StartingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                HeapSort(TestArray);
                long EndingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                IterationElapsedTime = EndingTime - StartingTime;
                ElapsedTime += IterationElapsedTime;
                if (IterationElapsedTime < MinTime) MinTime = IterationElapsedTime;
                if (IterationElapsedTime > MaxTime) MaxTime = IterationElapsedTime;
            }
            ElapsedTime -= (MinTime + MaxTime);
            ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedTime * (1000.0 / (NIter * Stopwatch.Frequency));
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}\t{1}", u, ElapsedSeconds.ToString("F4"));
        }
```

As You see, that what is changing is a sort method name. Basicly I want to change, this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nInsertionSort\nARRAY SIZE:\t TIME [ms]:");
    for (int u = 50000; u <= 200000; u += 10000)
    {
        int[] TestArray = new int[u];
        Array.Copy(ArrayRandom, TestArray, u);
        double ElapsedSeconds;
        long ElapsedTime = 0, MinTime = long.MaxValue, MaxTime = long.MinValue, IterationElapsedTime;
        for (int n = 0; n < (NIter + 1 + 1); ++n)  
        {
            long StartingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
            InsertionSort(TestArray);
            long EndingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
            IterationElapsedTime = EndingTime - StartingTime;
            ElapsedTime += IterationElapsedTime;
            if (IterationElapsedTime < MinTime) MinTime = IterationElapsedTime;
            if (IterationElapsedTime > MaxTime) MaxTime = IterationElapsedTime;
        }
        ElapsedTime -= (MinTime + MaxTime);
        ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedTime * (1000.0 / (NIter * Stopwatch.Frequency));
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}\t{1}", u, ElapsedSeconds.ToString("F4"));
    }
```

into somthing like this:

```
MethotImLookingFor(AnySort(TestArray));
```

Comment: Why do you not take that repeating part into another function and call it in this one?

Comment: So you want us to wade into that wall of nested loops and refactor it for you? You could probably just select the section of code you want to repeat in VS, right click, select "Refactor" or "Quick Actions and Refactorings" from the context menu (it changes with VS version, sorry), and choose "Extract Method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor the code that is repeated into a method that takes an `Action<int[]>` parameter.

Something like this (untested):

```
void Main()
{
    Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    int[] ArrayRandom = new int[200000];
    for (int j = 0; j < ArrayRandom.Length; j++) ArrayRandom[j] = rnd.Next(int.MaxValue);

    performSort("Heap Sort", ArrayRandom, HeapSort);
    performSort("Cocktail Sort", ArrayRandom, HeapSort);
    performSort("Selection Sort", ArrayRandom, HeapSort);
    performSort("Insertion Sort", ArrayRandom, HeapSort);
}

public void performSort(string sortName, int[] arrayToSort, Action<int[]> sortFunction)
{
    int[] ArrayRandom = arrayToSort;

    Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\nARRAY SIZE:\t TIME [ms]:", sortName);
    for (int u = 50000; u <= 200000; u += 10000)
    {
        int[] TestArray = new int[u];
        Array.Copy(ArrayRandom, TestArray, u);
        double ElapsedSeconds;
        long ElapsedTime = 0, MinTime = long.MaxValue, MaxTime = long.MinValue, IterationElapsedTime;
        for (int n = 0; n < (NIter + 1 + 1); ++n)
        {
            long StartingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
            sortFunction.Invoke(TestArray);
            long EndingTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
            IterationElapsedTime = EndingTime - StartingTime;
            ElapsedTime += IterationElapsedTime;
            if (IterationElapsedTime < MinTime) MinTime = IterationElapsedTime;
            if (IterationElapsedTime > MaxTime) MaxTime = IterationElapsedTime;
        }
        ElapsedTime -= (MinTime + MaxTime);
        ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedTime * (1000.0 / (NIter * Stopwatch.Frequency));
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}\t{1}", u, ElapsedSeconds.ToString("F4"));
    }
}

public void HeapSort(int[] array) { //Sorting code here }
public void CocktailSort(int[] array) { //Sorting code here }
public void InsertionSort(int[] array) { //Sorting code here }
public void SelectionSort(int[] array) { //Sorting code here }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass in a reference to your sort method instead of hard-coding it, then yes, you can have this method take in a delegate (function pointer) to your sort method:

```
private static void TimeMySortAlgorithm(Action<int[]> sortMethod)
{
    for (int u = 50000; u <= 200000; u += 10000)
    {
        int[] TestArray = new int[u];

        // Rest of the code

        // Invoke the delegate.
        sortMethod(TestArray);

        // Rest of the code
    }
}
```

And assuming you have an `InsertionSort` method like this:

```
private static void InsertionSort(int[] array) { }
```

You can call `TimeMySortAlgorithm` like the following:

```
TimeMySortAlgorithm(InsertionSort);
TimeMySortAlgorithm(CocktailSort);
TimeMySortAlgorithm(HeapSort);
```

Read more about [delegates here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/).